# instantiation and collections - ruby

Tags: ruby

I am a newb and struggling with making a test pass. I have 3 classes, artists, songs, and genres. The test I am trying to make pass is below:

```
test 'A genre has many artists' do
 genre = Genre.new.tap{|g| g.name = 'rap'}

 [1,2].each do
  artist = Artist.new
  song = Song.new
  song.genre = genre
  artist.add_song(song)
 end

assert_equal genre.artists.count, 2
end
```

This is my artist class, the add_song method is the one I need to tweak. When a song is added to an artist I am trying to instantiate a new Genre object and add the artist to that genre as well. Currently not working though, when I call genre.artists it returns an empty array.
    class Artist
     attr_accessor :name, :songs, :genres, :genre, :artists
     @@artists = []

```
 def initialize(name = name, genre = genre)
  @artists = []
  @songs = []
  @genre = genre
  @genres = []
  @name = name
  @@artists << self
 end

 def self.all
  @@artists
 end

 def self.reset_artists
  @@artists = []
 end

 def self.count
  self.all.size
 end

 def songs_count
  self.songs.size
 end

 def count
  self.size
  end

  def add_song(song)
   @songs << song
   @genres << song.genre
   Genre.new(self)
   end
  end

 class Genre
 attr_accessor :name, :songs, :artists
 @@genres = []

 def initialize(artists = artists)
  @songs = []
  @artists = artists
  @name = name
  @@genres << self
 end

 def count
  self.artists.count
  end

 def self.all
  @@genres
 end

 def self.reset_genres
  @@genre = []
 end 
end

class Song
attr_accessor :name, :genre, :artist

def initialize(name = name, artist = artist, genre = genre)
 @name = name
 @artist = artist
 @genre = genre
 end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new artist, you add it to `Artist::artists` - a class variable of `Artist`. The array you test is `genre.artists` - an object variable of `Genre`. That's a different variable from `Artist::artists`, and I don't see you updating `genre.artists` anywhere in your code - I'm surprised it's even an array, seeing that you don't initialize it to an array...

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a creating a new instance of Genre with the current artist in the `add_song` method. You could get your test to pass in a couple of ways.

This will add an artist to the genre referenced in the song instance.

```
def add_song(song)
  @songs << song
  @genres << song.genre
  song.genre.artists << self
end
```

The second option would be fix your test if you want to return a new Genre instance from your add_song method. This is most likely not what you want, however this would set artist the reference in Genre.

```
test 'A genre has many artists' do
  genre = Genre.new.tap{|g| g.name = 'rap'}

 [1,2].each do
   art ist = Artist.new
   song = Song.new
   song.genre = genre
   genre = artist.add_song(song)
 end 

 assert_equal genre.artists.count, 2
end
```

Comment: Thanks Austin, when I try to add the song.genre << self, I am receiving a no method error saying NoMethodError: undefined method `<<' for #<Genre:0x0000010187c150 @songs=[], @artists=nil, @name="rap">"   What is self in this case?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add the `.artists` to the method call. You want to add the current artist referenced by self to the artists array in genre.